# Как переделать функцию отрисовки текста в функцию отрисовки символа?(OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

Есть функция, хочу ее оптимизировать и превратить в функцию, которая рисует только один символ. Как это можно сделать?

```
GLvoid glText(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, const char* txt, GLuint basefont)
{
glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);
glRasterPos2d(x, y);
glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
glListBase(basefont);
glCallLists((GLsizei)strlen(txt), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txt);
glPopAttrib();
}
```

Comment: Передавайте один символ. Тут оптимизировать особо и нечего больше

Comment: @Kromster, я так и делаю) Просто хотел уточнить, можно ли как-то это сделать лучше)