# Freetype и freeglut. Как вывести текст с загруженным шрифтом?(C++)

Tags: c++, opengl

возник вопрос. Как с помощью freetype и freeglut вывести текст с загруженым шрифтом.
Функция вывода текста:

```
GLvoid glText(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, const char* txt, GLuint basefont)
{
glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);
glRasterPos2d(x, y);
glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
glListBase(basefont);
glCallLists((GLsizei)strlen(txt), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txt);
glPopAttrib();
}
```

Инициализацию шрифта делаю стандартно:

```
if (FT_Load_Glyph(face, FT_Get_Char_Index(face, ch), FT_LOAD_DEFAULT))

        throw std::runtime_error("FT_Load_Glyph failed");
```

только не понимаю, что с этим делать дальше. Как FT_Face преобразовать в GLuint.

Comment: *"преобразовать в GLuint"* Display list-ы не обязательно использовать. Вот годный туториал по выводу текста: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1154393/312941